# Command to remove schema from PostgreSQL backup in `directory` format

Tags: postgresql

I make a database backup using a command like (`-Fd` meaning "directory" format):

```
pg_dump -U postgres -Fd -j 8 -f testdb.dir testdb
```

My DB contains many schemas with personal data. At some point I might need to remove one schema from the backup. Restore&re-dump is not a feasible solution (too many backups).

So ideally I would need a command like `command --remove-schema=user123 testdb.dir`. That would just remove an appropriate `1234.dat.gz` file and perhaps update `toc.dat` inside `testdb.dir`.

PS: I know I can list contents with `pg_restore -l`, but haven't found docs describing format of the output file. I don't want to guess what is what and risk data loss.

Answer (score 1):

If you have segregated the data so that all of the PII is contained in one schema; you could exclude that schema from your dump.

From the man page for `pg_dump`:

```
   -N schema
   --exclude-schema=schema
       Do not dump any schemas matching the schema pattern. The pattern is interpreted
       according to the same rules as for -n.  -N can be given more than once to exclude
       schemas matching any of several patterns.

       When both -n and -N are given, the behavior is to dump just the schemas that match at
       least one -n switch but no -N switches. If -N appears without -n, then schemas matching
       -N are excluded from what is otherwise a normal dump.
```

This will break foreign key references from tables in other schemas in the recovered database. And it's only one way to do it; there are plenty of others depending on your use case.

If you are producing a data product you probably want to write a custom export script that removes dangling ID's and adds formatting and other features your consumers will want. Backup tools are designed primarily to preserve all of the data and are rather blunt in filtering it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it. You can try to remove it by `grep -p` but it is very complicate as for me. Probably is easier to remove schema after restoring